# With...End With VB6 Statement like Statement in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, object

Wondering if we have something like vb6 with..End With Statement in Objective-c?

Example:

```
With Object
     .a = "aaa";
     .b = "bbb"; 
End With
```

I know that there is something called blocks concept, but i am not sure whether it is available in 10.5 Leopard.

Thanks

Comment: You might try describing what you want, instead of referring to something else that most of us don't know about.

Comment: Sorry,i am coming from VB6 and .Net background. So most of my questions based on that only. I know working with objective-c is completely different.I'll try my best to describe my needs, more clearly to you next time.

Comment: Why not do it this time? You can edit your question to include a description of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, there is no such thing in Objective-C.

By the way, blocks (also known as closures) have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Sorry,i am newbie for mac development and didn't completely read all the features of objective-c. Thanks for your answer.