# Is there a "with" statement in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for something like:

```
with car.body.wheel 
begin
.airPressure = 3.0;
.diameter = 20;
end
```

I could write a macro for it I guess, but was wondering if there is anything build-in.

Comment: What is the type of `wheel`?  Is it an object or a struct?

Comment: An object. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it for structs?

Comment: Not generally, but if you happen to be assigning *all* fields of the struct, you can use a struct literal with designated initializers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With...End With VB6 Statement like Statement in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377259/with-end-with-vb6-statement-like-statement-in-objective-c)

Comment: You can create a special method or even a generic method(using kvc) for this kind of shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, there is no such thing in Objective C.

Just do this

```
XObject *x = car.body.wheel;
x.airPressure = 3.0;
x.diameter = 20;
```

Of course, change `XObject` to whatever type `wheel` is

Update: got rid of the id syntax

Comment: `<pedantic>` Actually, your "even better yet" is required.  Dot-syntax access on id is too ambiguous to compile. `</pedantic>`

Comment: Why cast it when you can declare `x` the right type in the first place?

Comment: Of course you guys are right, I was just lazy and didn't want to make up a fake class name. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

No. Rather than writing a macro for it, which is likely to make your code hard for other Objective-C programmers to read, you should just do it the normal ObjC way:

```
car.body.wheel.airPressure = 3.0;
car.body.wheel.diameter = 20;
```

Comment: I really fail to see the "hard for other Objective-C programmers to read" (if a macro would be used). Writing less is better, plus, is not like it's a cryptic thing, with the right tab align, could be quite OK.

Comment: Writing less is not always better. Particularly in Objective-C, where some level of verbosity (in method names, etc.) is standard and is a virtue. If I have to backtrack and look up a macro just to understand what should be some assignment statements, that's not a good thing...

Comment: Well, you don't need to backtrack it really, would be pretty obvious. But I guess is a matter of preference/background. I personally prefer things packed, concentrated so I don't need to read 10 lines of code to understand the same thing I could have by reading one packed line.

Comment: @ValentinRadu: Pascal had a "With" statement, and it was the biggest design mistake in the whole language.